# Extracting nth bit in hexadecimal value

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string representing a hexadecimal value such as "0x4", binary represented as 0100. If I want test whether the nth bit is set to 1, and where I count starting from the least significant bit (meaning in this example that only the 3rd bit is 1) how can I do this in the most elegant way?

I doubt the way I am doing is very elegant or efficient.
bits = '{0:08b}'.format(int(0x4, 16))
and then check if str(bits[-3]) is "1"

```py
bits = '{0:08b}'.format(int(0x4, 16))
if str(bits[-3]) == "1":
    print "Bit is set to 1"
```

I'd like a neat way of doing this, e.g. using bitwise operators or shifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if a bit is set, use the bitwise `&` on a bit mask of just that bit:

```
>>> bool(12 & 0b0100)
True
```

To get a bit mask set at the n-th position, bit-shift a `1` by `n-1` positions:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> 1 << n-1
4
>>> bin(1 << n-1)
'0b100'
```

Combined, you can directly check whether a specific bit is set:

```
>>> def bitset(number, n):
...     """Test whether ``number`` has the ``n``'th bit set"""
...     return bool(number & 1 << n - 1)
...
>>> bitset(0x4, 3)
```

If your input is a string (instead of generating a string from an integer), use `int` to convert it:

```
>>> bitset(int('0x4', 16), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd use [bitwise operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) for that:

```
if 4 & 1 << n:
    print('Bit', n, 'is set')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`bin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) function to convert an integer to a binary string:

```
>>> n = int('0x4', 16)
>>> n
4
>>> bin(n)
'0b100'
>>> bin(n)[-3] == '1'
True
```

A more efficient way would be to operate on the integer directly using bitwise operators:

```
>>> bool(n & 1<<2)  # shift "1" 2 bits to the left and use bitwise and
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def check_nth_bit(str_hex, nth_bit):
    return (int(str_hex, 16) & 2 **(nth_bit - 1)) >> (nth_bit - 1) == 1

print(check_nth_bit('0x4', 3))
print(check_nth_bit('0x4', 1))
```

output:

```
True
False
```